# jQuery like architecture

Tags: javascript, jquery, architecture, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to create a jQuery like architecture in my app but i could not get my expected results.

In jQuery "The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'".

```
jQuery = function( selector, context ) {
    return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
},
```

That means when you initiate the jQuery object with;

```
$('selector')
```

jQuery returns the

```
new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
```

jQuery prototype is defines as;

```
jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype = {
constructor: jQuery,
init: function( selector, context, rootjQuery ) {
    var match, elem, ret, doc;
            ...
            return jQuery.makeArray( selector, this ); // An array
    }
...
size: function() {
    return this.length;
},
...
```

all the usefull properties and methods of jQuery (like hide(), show() exct.) are hold by prototype of the jQuery object.

And the prototype of the init method assigns as the prototype of the jQuery;

```
jQuery.fn.init.prototype = jQuery.fn;
```

Well!. My problem is I tried to use this architecture but I could not get the properties and methods of the returned value.

Here is my code;

```
(function() {

Metinler = function(MetinKodu){
    return new Metinler.sub.baslat( MetinKodu );
}



Metinler.sub = Metinler.prototype = {
    metinKodlari: [],
    constructor: Metinler,
    topla: function(){
        return this.metinKodlari[0] + this.metinKodlari[1];
    },
    baslat: function(MetinKodu) {
        if($.isArray(MetinKodu) && MetinKodu.length > 0) {

            this.metinKodlari = MetinKodu;
        }else{
            this.metinKodlari = (MetinKodu) ? [MetinKodu] : [''];
        }

        return this.metinKodlari;
    }
}
Metinler.sub.baslat.prototype = Metinler.sub;

window.Metinler = Metinler;

})()
```

[Code](http://jsfiddle.net/NBnR5/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are seeing, is that your constructor is returning a specific value:

```
return this.metinKodlari;
```

... which returns your internal array (well, you array of an array).

Remove this line and you'll return your `baslat` instance.

Answer (score 1):

Your `baslat` function is faulty:

- You misspelled `length` in `MetinKodu.lenght > 0`.
- You're returning the `metinKodlari` array, whereas you should return the newly created `this` context. jQuery uses `makeArray` on `this` to store the passed DOM elements in the array-like jQuery object. In your case however, you simply want to store the passed elements in the `metinKodlari` array instead of on the `this` object itself.

This should work:

```
    baslat: function(MetinKodu) {
        if ($.isArray(MetinKodu) && MetinKodu.length > 0) {
            this.metinKodlari = MetinKodu;
        } else {
            this.metinKodlari = (MetinKodu) ? [MetinKodu] : [''];
        }
        return this;
    }
```